# Not able to use <QJsonValue> <QJsonObject>

Tags: qt

I have a problem using 
 QJsonValue and 
 QJsonObject

even when I add QT+=core.
I am using QT 5.5
Does anyone knows what could be the problem.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by problems? Describe the problem, and put your code??

Comment: I have not write any code yet, but when I write to  include those libraries it says Nosuch file or directory

Comment: Ok, you need to give a bit more information, could you add your code lines, or your project file? And by the way, your mentioned error message would also be good.

Comment: The code is in the answer

Comment: Is there a posibility that it is not included in my qt, Wnhen I ask for the version of qmake I get: QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.5.1 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
Is this enough to use QJson

Comment: And one more question I am also using APM_Planner and I supose that it has to work with json data but it compiles normaly, but when I try to build my own project it fails.

Answer (score 0):

```
Pro file:     

QT  += core gui webkit network
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp \
apiservis.cpp
HEADERS += \
apiservis.h
QT = core
QT -= gui
QT += webkit
QT += webkit webkitwidgets
QT += network
TARGET = cpp
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
TARGET = main
DISTFILES += \
API_kljuc.txt   

And in the .h file I have:  
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <QHash>
#include <QVariantMap>
#include <QWebFrame>
#include <QWebView>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QObject>
#include <QJsonArray>
#include <QJsonValue>
#include <QJsonObject>

But when I try to build it, error is: QJsonARRay:No such file or directory.
```

Comment: I have solved the problem. I had two versions of qt 4.8 and 5.5 and it used 4.8. After unistalling 4.8 it worked.